# tutorial_server_data.py error 400: {"error":"partial write: points beyond retention policy dropped=4320"}

Tags: python, python-3.x, influxdb, influxdb-python

> Link: https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-python/blob/master/examples/tutorial_server_data.py

- it's probably a beginner question.

> I tried to copy that example, but when I ran in the Terminal I received this message:
>
> Terminal:

```
python3 tutorial_server_data.py 

python3 tutorial_server_data.py --host 'localhost' --port 8086 --nb_day 15

...

Create database: tutorial
Create a retention policy
Write points #: 4320
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tutorial_server_data.py", line 93, in <module>
    main(host=args.host, port=args.port, nb_day=args.nb_day)
  File "tutorial_server_data.py", line 63, in main
    client.write_points(series, retention_policy=retention_policy)
  File "/home/joaoguilherme/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 530, in write_points
    consistency=consistency)
  File "/home/joaoguilherme/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 598, in _write_points
    protocol=protocol
  File "/home/joaoguilherme/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 343, in write
    headers=headers
  File "/home/joaoguilherme/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 302, in request
    raise InfluxDBClientError(response.content, response.status_code)
influxdb.exceptions.InfluxDBClientError: 400: {"error":"partial write: points beyond retention policy dropped=4320"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not but this is actually running as expected (or as coded too).

If you look at line 60

> ```
> client.create_retention_policy(retention_policy, '3d', 3, default=True)
> ```

a 3 day retention policy is created, so any data over 3 days are automatically dropped

Youve given it a 15d flag, so you are dropping 12 days worth of data.

Looking at the script, its actually incorrectly written and i wouldnt use it. i.e it allows you to specify the nb_day value but is hard coded to 15 (line 20) .